# Build multiline chart using d3.js from using .csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am using the following `JavaScript` to plot the Multiline graph. I followed this [Link](http://bl.ocks.org/kramer/4745936)

But no data is getting displayed. Also I am new to the whole `JavaScript`

Format of my `.csv` file is following and I want to read from Second column onwards where i want to plot `favorite_count` and `retweet_count` in Y-Axis and `created_at` at X-Axis:

**TSV format**

```
idtweet         created_at                      favorite_count  retweet_count 
 1311613481     Wed Mar 11 17:24:26 +0000 2009      0           1 
 10293166856    Wed Mar 10 22:57:09 +0000 2010      0           1
 10881883917    Mon Mar 22 17:21:47 +0000 2010      0           1
```

My Code where I am not able to understand that where should I paas Y-axis `favourite_count` and `retweet_count` values?

**MY Code**

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="d3.legend.js"></script>
<script>


var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.created_at); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("/home/hduser/Downloads/MyTSV.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[1]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "created_at"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.created_at = parseDate(d.created_at);
  });

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {created_at: d.created_at, temperature: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.created_at; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Number of Tweets");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return d.name})
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.created_at) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


  legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","legend")
    .attr("transform","translate(50,30)")
    .style("font-size","12px")
    .call(d3.legend)

  setTimeout(function() { 
    legend
      .style("font-size","20px")
      .attr("data-style-padding",10)
      .call(d3.legend)
  },1000)

});
```

Can anybody guide me that what direction should I follow ? I am new to this whole concept.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no its displaying nothing.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff also when I converted `.csv` to `.tsv`, it just displays X and Y axis, but its just parsing Year not the whole date, so thats why nothing is being displayed on bar chart on Y axis.

Comment: Your code has `d3.csv` in it. Is the file you're trying to load a CSV or TSV?

Comment: Yeah at first I was using `d3.csv` to parse but when it was not working i converted my CSV to TSV and used `d3.tsv` to parse the it just displayed X and Y axis and no chart is being displayed.

Comment: May be its having problem of parsing the date, but m not able to understand

Comment: Did you see my comment to your question about parsing the date?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes actually I have seen that, but m not able to understand that why its not working with my graph. Not able to understand that what I need to do to make it work. As I am new to this whole concept

Comment: Could you provide a complete example (code and data) so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How do we change given parsed date `Wed Mar 11 17:24:26 +0000 2009` in `20090311` format in js

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have actually provided my sample data and code.

As my sample data contains `idtweet` i dont want to use that I just want to reading from second column and `created_at` part on X-Axis and build my double line graph with `favorite_count` and `retweet_count` columns.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I meant that In example of this graph the date is in format `20090311` but my date is in format `Wed Mar 11 17:24:26 +0000 2009` is this giving the problem in plotting the graph.

As I rarely code on JS am not able to understand

Comment: Well I have no problems getting a graph with what you have posted: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8y3osqnxkMdlJY7UGsv?p=preview

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am not getting any of the values on Y-axis actually. Ok lemme check where I am going wrong

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Does D3 takes `.csv` and `.tsv` as synonyms? because you have used function `d3.csv` and file extension is `.tsv` even though the file is comma seperated

Comment: The file extension doesn't matter. I used CSV because the tabs got messed up when copying and pasting.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This is what I am getting when I copied my sample `data.csv` http://plnkr.co/edit/6D1fxHcXwNVNfqmsjP7L?p=preview

Comment: The dates you have in there are invalid (and nothing like anything you've posted here).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Actually I might have messed up my dummy data with various RnD's now I have updated the file. And the thing is its showing `idtweet` on graph why is it so ? what if I want to show `favourite_count` and `tweet_count` lines ?

So sorry for bothering you this much sir I am not able to understand this actually :(

Comment: The code you're using is showing everything except `created_at`. It may be easier for you to start with a single line and once that's working add the second one.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have developed this http://plnkr.co/edit/JVZaW33yzkggBYHeBGZZ?p=preview new graph but still its giving me prob with the date.

What shounl I do for that, will u be able to help me?

Comment: You had some tabs in your date strings that cause parsing problems -- http://plnkr.co/edit/KF6V1G0tiZoGjGhkGMZW?p=preview